# How to stop simulation from the code?

Tags: omnet++

I want my simulation to stop as soon as a specific condition in the code is met. By 'stop' I mean it should pause the simulation as if I pressed stop button in the simulation window. So that I could continue the simulation with a slower speed from this moment.

Is there a way to do it from the module code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for managing the GUI's run state. The reason is, that you can run the simulation also in Cmdenv without recompiling the code and it's not possible/makes no sense to *pause* a simulation in Cmdenv.

You can however do a trick, because the simulation is repeatable:

- Add some code that prints out the event number when the specific condition occurred.
- Run the simulation and note the event number it prints out when the simulation is run.
- Now start the simulation again (with the same parameters) but use the "Run until... /  Event number" and specify the event number where the GUI should stop.

Answer (score 1):

The `alert()` method is very convenient to implement @Rudi trick.
In GUI (Run, Fast, and Express) `alert()` pauses the simulation, shows a message box with own text, waits for user reaction, and then continues the simulation in the same mode. In `Cmdenv` it shows a text in console without pausing a simulation.
Here is a sample code that prints current event number using this method:

```
char text[128];
sprintf(text,"Event number: %lld", getSimulation()->getEventNumber());
getSimulation()->getActiveEnvir()->alert(text);
```

After learning this event number one should do what @Rudi has proposed in the last bullet.

Comment: Indeed. While outputting the event number in a log is ok, these interactive methods help you to avoid searching for the event number in the log. Sadly if I remember correctly these dialogs are modal so you cannot actually pause the simulation when they are shown. However it would be an interesting feature request to have a "pause" button on that dialog....